# Curvature vs Gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature, geodesics

I understand how and why spacetime curvature is responsible for the formation of geodesics and how objects follow those curved spacetime paths.

"Matter tells spacetime how to bend and spacetime tells matter how to move"

However if an object is dropped from any height. How does the object that's causing the curvature (gravity) not cause the falling object to have a different impact location in the outcome other than straight down - if the falling object is following a geodesic - a curved path?

And if straight down is following some geodesics. If a geodesics is bent to that extreme as to be straight down that would be a black hole environment. So that can't be it.

But if down is not the straightest path in a curved spacetime that still doesn't make any sense as all objects always fall straight down. "Spacetime tell matter how to move".

Which means geodesics.

In fact, if dropped two objects 100 miles up above two different planets with radically different gravitational potentials, different curvatures, the objects I drop (provided the planets are not rotating) will always fall straight down.

The planet with the greatest gravity, the greatest curvature wouldn't cause the object to fall at different location other than straight down because its curvature has a greater magnitude.

And if both curvature causing planets causes falling objects to only falling straight down. That's like saying the object causing the greater gravitational field (curvature) will cause objects to fall "straighter" down towards it. Huh?

Thus how can we then say that "curvature” is responsible for what we call “gravity”? Curvature causing the formation of geodesics sure, but physically pulling something straight down a radial path - how?

Comment: Your question is confusing. A body falling straight down in space *is* following a geodesic in curved spacetime.

Comment: @ProfRob I'll pass on your advice as non of the statements I've made are untrue.

Comment: "Down" is not defined in General Relativity.  Despite your protestations you do _not_ appear to understand what a geodesic is.

Comment: _If_ I did not, I would do my own research rather than bothering people here.

Comment: For your last question, it seems to me that you forget that the curvature is the space-time curvature and not just space curvature. Nothing is pulling anything when an object is following a geodesic in space-time: just as Alice and Bob that are initially parallel on the equator and walking to the north pole will meet at this pole without walking along tropics, an object will fall down to earth without being pulled down, because trajectories of earth and this object in time meet at some point in space-time.

Comment: There is no sense in which asking a question here is "research"!

Comment: @Brick your definition of "research" is different from my definition. You do you and I'll do me.

Comment: @Jeanbaptiste Roux so if I drop an object from 1 inch above the ground that object is still following a geodesic which is causing the object to fall radial toward the planet? That seems unlikely.

Comment: Geodesics and thus curvature fall under gravitation. I'm talking about gravity which is what causes the earth to pull something radially inward. What's the source of that? Gravitation and gravity are not the same things.

Answer (score 6):

An object whose path is a straight line in the three spatial dimensions of spacetime can still be following a curve in the time dimension if it is accelerating. This is what happens when an object falls “straight down” under gravity.

If an object followed a straight line in space *and* time then it would be moving in a straight line in space at a constant velocity. Ballistic objects in a gravitational field (whether they are thrown or just dropped) follow geodesics in spacetime. The fact the these geodesics are *not* straight lines in spacetime shows that spacetime is not flat.

Comment: Sorry but that can't it either.

Comment: @PythonHouse I don't understand you comment. Can you say more ?

Comment: You answer doesn't offer any mechanics. You're invoking Deus Ex Machina to say a curvature in time is the cause, which also happens to be incorrect. Geodesics cause objects (such as light and Mercury) to curve around a body such as the sun. It doesn't cause objects to be pulled radially inward. The sun's geodesics is causing Mercury to shift its perihelion but what's causing Mercury to be pulled radially towards the sun to begin with?

Comment: @PythonHouse I suggest you read this Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity. “A freely moving or falling particle always moves along a geodesic”.

Comment: I have and it offers no explanation as to why objects fall radially inward. Geodesics only determine how objects move because of a gravitational mass. It says absolutely nothing about the cause of what pulls an object straight down. A geodesic pointing directly radially inward would be an extreme geodesics. Even the sun's geodesics aren't that strong. Even the geodesics around black holes aren't that strong which is why light is still able to orbit the hole. But somehow the geodesics on earth are strong enough to pull an object straight down is not possible.

Comment: Geodesics and thus curvature fall under gravitation. I'm talking about gravity which is what causes the earth to pull something radially inward. What's the source of that? Gravitation and gravity are not the same things.

Comment: @PythonHouse You seem to have a misunderstanding independent of general relativity. Nothing about a path radially inwards is an "extreme geodesic", this notion does NOT even have a meaning. The reason why the ISS is in Earth's orbit and and an apple falls down is just because the ISS is fast enough (meaning orbital speed) to be in a stable orbit. If the ISS could brake and come to a full stop, it would just "fall down" FOR THE SAME REASON IT IS IN ORBIT. There is nothing extreme about this geodesic. Maybe it would help going back to Newton's mechanics and the Kepler problem.

Comment: You misunderstood my meaning. I do not think that a radially inward path means an extreme geodesic. I'm trying to convey the opposite that the geodesic is not responsible for the radial fall of an object. And if the geodesic are not responsible that what mechanism is?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are taking the term *curvature* too literal here. While general relativity says objects on which no forces (besides gravity) act, follow geodesics, which can be curved or more complicated paths, nothing prevents a geodesic from being a straight line in some special cases. This also does NOT mean that the geodesic is "extremely bent" (you seem to assume a geodesic has to be extremely bent to "become" straight), which is kind of a meaningless notion.

If an object initially has ONLY radial velocity regarding to a large central mass (i.e. it only moves in the radial direction towards the center of the large mass), the geodesic will just be a straight path regarding to the center of the large mass. Also this is NOT only possible in the vicinity of a black hole. Quite contrary, gravitationally, a planet like Earth does not care if in the center of the solar system is the Sun or a black hole with 1 solar mass. Far away from this object (Sun or black hole), the curved space-time looks the same.

You should also note that a straight spatial path does not mean it is necessarily straight in four dimensional space-time, i.e. a falling object with a straight spatial path towards the center is still accelerating and therefore does not follow a straight path if you include the time dimension.

Comment: *Immediately* outside the object, not far away from the object.

Comment: So my expression should still be correct. If the space-time is the same immediately outside of the object, it is also the same far away (contrary to what you wrote, since you probably meant "not *only* far way"). I wanted to avoid discussions about the Schwartzschild radius in Schwartzschild metric, since the Sun is far bigger than it's Schwartzschild radius and therefore you can of course not use the Schwartzschild metric for the Sun for r being smaller than the Sun's radius (which is also not easy to define exactly).

Comment: Geodesics and thus curvature fall under gravitation. I'm talking about gravity which is what causes the earth to pull something radially inward. What's the source of that? Gravitation and gravity are not the same things.

Comment: @PythonHouse, I do not know why you write "Geodesics and thus curvature fall under *gravitation*", but in the following refer to *gravity* of the Earth as something DIFFERENT. The gravitational field around the Earth is described by curvature of space-time, where the latter can lead to objects accelerating radially towards the Earth's center, leading to paths that look straight, but are still geodesics. The whole phenomenon is called gravity or gravitation. I am pretty sure both words mean the same thing. If you think this is not the case, feel free to specify what you think is the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a curved path in *spacetime* is not necessarily a curved path in *space*. An object dropped to Earth from height $y_0$ has a height at time $t$ that's calculated as $y(t) = y_0 - 9.8 t^2$. An object dropped on the Moon from the same height follows the path $y'(t) = y_0 - 1.67 t^2$. If you plot the graphs of these two functions you'll see that they're both curves, and indeed they're both different curves.

In our everyday experience the warping of time due to matter is overwhelmingly more important than any warping of space. That warping can be directly measured. For example, atomic clocks are now sensitive enough so that if one is placed even one third of a meter higher than another, the higher one will be observed to be ticking faster (see [this link](https://www.nist.gov/news-events/news/2010/09/nist-pair-aluminum-atomic-clocks-reveal-einsteins-relativity-personal-scale) for details).

Comment: Geodesics and thus curvature fall under gravitation. I'm talking about gravity which is what causes the earth to pull something radially inward. What's the source of that? Gravitation and gravity are not the same things.

Comment: Why do you think "gravitation" and "gravity" are different things???

Comment: Because they are. Do your research. https://byjus.com/physics/difference-between-gravitation-and-gravity/

Comment: That link is nonsense. The laws of gravitation are universal and certainly apply to the Earth just as much as to any other object.

Comment: Sorry but only someone who has never studied general Relativity would think that there's no difference between gravitation and gravity and not understand why they are different. Keep studying.

Comment: Certainly one of us needs to do some studying, perhaps starting with the very first sentences of https://www.britannica.com/science/gravity-physics or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity. Your question has been answered here by multiple people, if you don't want to accept it that's up to you.

Comment: No one here has answered anything. Least of all you. But as I said do you own research and stop taking education from wiki and britannica.

Answer (score 0):

The commonly used image of a "bowling ball in a trampoline" model of curved spacetime is very deceptive because it implies a curved fall path, as you have described.  I prefer to look at gravity as operating exactly like a low pressure system in the weather,.  You can see below a typical weather low pressure system, and an image of the Earth as a low pressure system of "time".

Or even in fact like the lower water pressure as you rise from the bottom of the ocean.  If you release a cork from the bottom of the ocean, it will rise straight up, regardless of the gravity of the planet you are on.  Likewise, if you drop an object it will fall straight down, regardless of the planet.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Geodesics and thus curvature fall under gravitation. I'm talking about gravity which is what causes the earth to pull something radially inward. What's the source of that? Gravitation and gravity are not the same things.

Comment: @PythonHouse  I recently wrote a paper that attempts to provide an explanation of "matter tells spacetime how to curve".   So this would provide one possible answer to your question above, "what causes the earth to pull something inward."  This is only a concept at this point  - not even a theory.  So don't take it too seriously and definitely don't quote it.   https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D7718709_68878570_6399503